# Python won't evaluate specific 'if' condition

Tags: python

In my source code are 3 'if' statements. Suppose I type 'no' in the first loop, Python only goes so far as to evaluate the 2nd 'if' condition and not the 3rd 'if'. There is a difference if I change the order of the 2nd and 3rd if statements.

What can I do to get the 3rd 'if' statement to evaluate? Below is my code:

---

```
grid = [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]

def fill_grid(grid,pos,player):
    grid[pos[0]][pos[1]]=player
    print_grid(grid)

def print_grid(grid):
    for row in grid:
        for row_item in row:
            print(f'[{row_item}]',end=' ')
        print()

while True:
    continue_filling = input('Want to fill?')
    if (continue_filling == 'yes'):
        player=input('Which player?')
        row_col = [int(num_str) - 1 for num_str in input('Enter row and column:').split(',')]
        fill_grid(grid, row_col, player)
    elif (continue_filling != 'yes' or continue_filling != 'no'):
        print('Type yes or no!')
    elif (continue_filling == 'no'):
        break

print('Fill ended!')
```

---

### Below is the output:

Want to fill?no

Type yes or no!

Want to fill?no

Type yes or no!

Want to fill?dsbfdgn

Type yes or no!

Want to fill?yes

Which player?

Comment: `continue_filling` cannot be "yes" and "no" at the same time. One of the two *"is not equal to"* conditions will always be true!

Comment: If `continue_filling` need `and` rather than `or`.  Also, you don't need parens around the conditions.  Thus: ``elif continue_filling != 'yes' and continue_filling != 'no':`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the 2nd IF statement carefully,

`continue_filling != 'yes' or continue_filling != 'no'`

the value, `no`, is evaluated as true for the 1st condition, because `continue_filling` is NOT a 'yes'. Therefore, the 3rd IF statement is never reached.